# How can schemes see two points associated with $y = x^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have read somewhere that one motivation of scheme theory is that using methods developed in scheme theory we can detect that the point associated to the intersection of $y = 0 \cap y = x^2$ has multiplicity two. Can someone explain this in details to me. That would be very helpful.

Comment: $k[x,y]/ (y - x^2, y) = k[x,y] / (y,x^2) = k[x]/(x^2)$. The final ring is a vector space of dimension 2, which is the multiplicity of the intersection.

Comment: If you really want _all_ the details, you might have to start studying scheme theory. I recommend _"The geometry of schemes"_, by Eisenbud and Harris.

Comment: What does this have to do with schemes? This is the oldest idea in AG.